# ServiceStack Ormlite OnDelete="CASCADE" not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have the following ORM classes:

```cs
public class HotelProperties
{
    [AutoIncrement, PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public List<HotelRoomInfo> HotelRoomInfo { get; set; }
}

public class HotelRoomInfo
{
    [AutoIncrement, PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(HotelProperties), OnDelete = "CASCADE")]
    public int HotelPropertiesId { get; set; }
}
```

the `db.Load()` and `db.Save()` methods work perfectly fine, however, when I try deleting `HotelProperties`, I'm expecting `HotelRoomInfo` to be deleted too. I am not sure why is it not working?

I looked through [ForeignKeyAttributeTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/ForeignKeyAttributeTests.cs) and it seems correct. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you are sitting this model on top of a pre-existing database schema, and that you did not ask ServiceStack to *create* the table. It is entirely possible that only does anything in the create script, via the `ON DELETE CASCADE` syntax during `FOREIGN KEY` construction (specifically, the `REFERENCES` constraint). If so, and if you created the table and foreign key yourself *without* this option, then: it won't have any effect.

These options are discussed [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179610.aspx); look for "Cascading Referential Integrity"

Comment: yup your guess is right, I deleted the table and recreate via ServiceStack and the delete works. Thanks!